# How to use LazyDataModel List in a selectOneMenu

Tags: primefaces

I want to use a LazyDataModel List inside a SelectOneMenu, but the selectoneMenu doesn't show anything . this is my code

```
public void show() {

    beneficiaries = new LazyDataModel<Fournisseur>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<Fournisseur> list;

    @Override
    public List<Fournisseur> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,Object> filters){

        list = service.getAll((String)filters.get("benef.intitule"),first, pageSize);
        this.setRowCount(service.count((String)filters.get("benef.intitule")));
        return list;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Fournisseur obj) {
        return obj.getCpt();
    }
    @Override
    public Fournisseur getRowData(String rowKey) {
        Fournisseur o=null;
        if(rowKey != null) {
        for (Fournisseur obj : list) {
            if(rowKey == obj.getCpt()) {
                o = obj;
            }
        }
        return o;
        }else {
          return null;
        }
    }
    };

}
```

this is my html code

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="beneficiary" value="# 
{documentController.doc.beneficiary}" converter="# 
{beneficiaryConverter}" panelStyle="width:160px" required="true"  >
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner" itemValue=""  />
<f:selectItems  value="#{beneficiaryController.beneficiaries}" 
var="beneficiary" itemLabel="#{beneficiary.intitule}" itemValue="# 
{beneficiary}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

i've tested the list out side the selectOneMenu and it's work fine.

Comment: I don't believe that you can use LazyDataModel in Selectone menu.  It was meant for the DataTable component.

Comment: Ok that what i was suspecting , so if you don't mind how can we use a lazy method in SelectOneMenu .bcz the list is very big (over 6000 rows)

Comment: Don't. Use `autoComplete`. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml

Comment: ok thank you i'll try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using PrimeFaces and want to allow the user to select one out of very many options. As Melloware mentioned, `LazyDataModel` is ment for use with `DataTable` or other components that support pagination this way ( e.g. `DataGrid`)

For your use case [`p:autoComplete`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) seemes to be the best way to go.

`dropdown="true"` makes it look like a selectOneMenu, and you can limit the number of items show using `maxResults="5"`.

> ```
> <p:autoComplete dropdown="true" maxResults="5" value="#{autoCompleteView.txt6}"
>    completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeText}" />
> ```

You'll need to write a custom autoComplete method that finds matches for given user search input:

```
public List<String> completeText(String query) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    // fill the result matching the query from user input
    return results;
}
```